# Array() and Array.prototype usage

Tags: javascript

First of all i would like to ask for excuse if answer is obvious, and/or easy to find.
I didn't find any complete answers.

The question is very simple:

```
var array1 = Array().slice.call(arguments,1);
var array2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
```

They do the same thing.
Can you do in such a way for Object, Date, String, etc prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, simply because each instance inherits from its constructor's prototype.

That is `(new Array()).slice` (or better, `[].slice`) is exactly the same method as `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: It should be noted that while this works for Arrays because of the way the spec sets up behavior of `Array` (as a constructor) when called as a function, this does *not* necessarily extend to the other objects mentioned in the question. For example, if you do `Date.prototype.test = 1;` and then `Date().test`, you get nothing because of the way Date (as a constructor) acts as a function.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about mentioning this, but I did not want to make it too confusing. It's enough to say that `Date` does not return a `Date` instance when called without the `new` keyword (it returns a string).

Comment: Yeah, I think the constructor/function duality is probably more of the one confusing aspects of JavaScript.

Comment: For example? `Number().toFixed.call(5.12, 1)` is the same as `Number.prototype.toFixed.call(5.12, 1)`...

Comment: @Elmor: Ah well, that is something completely different. You cannot assign properties to primitive values.

Comment: To sum up the discussion:
You should use Array() & etc to access build in functions.
Number().toFixed.call(...)
But should use Number.prototype tho expand a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better, as you're not creating an Array that is otherwise unused.  With the first approach, you're constructing an array, and then using dynamic prototype chain resolution to locate it's slice method, which you then `call` using your arguments as the context.  The second approach directly access the `slice` method, so you're avoiding the object creation and prototype chain resolution, so it's all around better.